# Spock check number of methods call for private object

Tags: grails, testing, spock

I've created a service for REST call 3rd party api. There is a RestBuilder instance:

```
class ThirdPartyApiService{
    ...    
    private def restClient = new RestBuilder()
    ...
}
```

In test I want to check how many times **restClient.post(...)** is called. Tried to use Spies for it but no success.

```
class ThirdPartyApiServiceIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    def thirdPartyApiService

    def "test smthing"() {
        setup: "prepare spies"
        def restBuilderSpy = GroovySpy(RestBuilder, global: true)

        when:
        thirdPartyApiService.someMethod()

        then:
        1 * restBuilderSpy.post(* _)
    }
}
```

It fails with
**|  Too few invocations for:

1 * restBuilderSpy.post(*_)   (0 invocations)**

Have I missed something? How can I achieve my poin?

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing one beautiful line of code in the test. ;)

```
setup: "prepare spies"
    def restBuilderSpy = GroovySpy(RestBuilder, global: true)
    thirdPartyApiService.restClient = restBuilderSpy
```

Comment: Nope, how to deal with private field? And if use your suggestion no need in global:true param